# Task :expo-camera:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-camera, nx-monorepo

I am getting the issue `Task :expo-camera:compileDebugKotlin FAILED` when I try to integrate expo-camera with my expo react-native application configured in nx monorepo. This is my package.json

```
dependencies: {
    .
    .
    "expo": "50.0.6",
    "expo-camera": "14.0.5",
    "expo-constants": "15.4.5",
    "expo-linking": "6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "3.4.7",
    "expo-splash-screen": "0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "1.11.1",
    .
    .
}
```

I have ejected the expo app and built android and ios apps separately. In the android/build.gradle I added this as mentioned in expo docs (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera-next/)

```
maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
```

This is the entire stack trace

```
Task :expo-camera:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: file:///.../node_modules/expo-camera/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/camera/ExpoCameraView.kt:279:25 Unresolved reference: raw
e: file:///.../node_modules/expo-camera/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/camera/next/ExpoCameraView.kt:424:25 Unresolved reference: raw
e: file:///.../node_modules/expo-camera/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/camera/next/analyzers/BarcodeAnalyzer.kt:54:81 Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but (Mutable)List<Int!>! was expected
e: file:///.../node_modules/expo-camera/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/camera/next/analyzers/BarcodeAnalyzer.kt:54:86 Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<Int> but Int was expected
e: file:///.../node_modules/expo-camera/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/camera/next/analyzers/BarcodeAnalyzer.kt:54:113 Too many arguments for public constructor BarCodeScannerResult(p0: Int, p1: String!, p2: (Mutable)List<Int!>!, p3: Int, p4: Int) defined in expo.modules.interfaces.barcodescanner.BarCodeScannerResult
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you update your app.json with the following?

{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-camera",
        {
          "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera",
          "microphonePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone",
          "recordAudioAndroid": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}